# Action Script 3 (Flash) Timer - I cant set Timer properly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer, using

I got function in Flash (Action Script 3) - that makes snowflakes falling. Now i want to make this snowflakes appear on screen only for 3 seconds. So I'm trying to use Timer class but i got problem:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1); 
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, snowflakes);
myTimer.start();

function snowflakes(event:TimerEvent):void {
 //snowflakes faling function
}
```

In this case snowflakes appear **after 3 seconds** and stay on the stage forver...So its kinda opposite what i wanted. I want them to appear from the very beginning then disappear after 3 second. How can I do that ?

...EDIT

Oh yes. I do apologies for that. Here is the code. I got snowFlakes class in separate file called Snowflake.as which contains that code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Snowflake extends MovieClip
    {
        private var xPos:Number = 0;
        private var yPos:Number = 0;

        private var xSpeed:Number = 0;
        private var ySpeed:Number = 0;

        private var radius:Number = 0;

        private var scale:Number = 0;
        private var alphaValue:Number = 0;

        private var maxHeight:Number = 0;
        private var maxWidth:Number = 0;

        public function Snowflake()
        {
            //SetInitialProperties();
        }

        public function SetInitialProperties()
        {
            //Setting the various parameters that need tweaking 
            xSpeed = .05 + Math.random()*.1;
            ySpeed = .1 + Math.random()*6;
            radius = .1 + Math.random()*2;
            scale = .01 + Math.random();
            alphaValue = .1 + Math.random();

            var stageObject:Stage = this.stage as Stage;
            maxWidth = stageObject.stageWidth;
            maxHeight = stageObject.stageHeight;

            this.x = Math.random()*maxWidth;
            this.y = Math.random()*maxHeight;

            xPos = this.x;
            yPos = this.y;

            this.scaleX = this.scaleY = scale;
            this.alpha = alphaValue;

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveSnowFlake);
        }

        function MoveSnowFlake(e:Event)
        {
            xPos += xSpeed;
            yPos += ySpeed;

            this.x += radius*Math.cos(xPos);
            this.y += ySpeed;

            if (this.y - this.height > maxHeight)
            {
                this.y = -10 - this.height;
                this.x = Math.random()*maxWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and first frame on the timeline on AS layer contains that code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);
myTimer.start();

function runOnce(event:TimerEvent):void {
 for (var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        var newSnowFlake:Snowflake = new Snowflake();
        this.addChild(newSnowFlake);

        newSnowFlake.SetInitialProperties();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timer is set just fine, the issue you're having is what you're doing with it.
Call snowFlakes right from the start, and bind the timer Event to removeSnowFlakes, where you will removeChild all snow flakes you added on the snowflakes function.

EDIT:

Apply the following changes to your code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var snowFlakeContainer : MovieClip;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, removeSnowFlakes);
myTimer.start();

addSnowFlakes();

function addSnowFlakes():void {
    snowFlakeContainer = new MovieClip();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        var newSnowFlake:Snowflake = new Snowflake();
        snowFlakeContainer.addChild(newSnowFlake);

        newSnowFlake.SetInitialProperties();
    }
}

function removeSnowFlakes(event:TimerEvent):void {
    removeChild(snowFlakeContainer);
    snowFlakeContainer = null;
}
```

Comment: Ok i get it. Thanks. I got one more question - how can i remove whole snowflakes function ? using removeChild is not working for functions. All i want to achieve is to disable snowflakes function after 3 sec ;). Do I need to create other function (like removeSnowFlakes) or there is a solution for disable snowflakes function after 3 seconds ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: ... You are not making alot of sense. What do you mean by remove the function??

Comment: I mean remove function activity (that creates snowflakes). So i want this function to stop after 3 seconds- its like remove it from "timeline" after 3 seconds. so maybe remove is a bad word. After 3 second i want this snowFlakes functions to stop being executed so snowFlakes do not appear any more. So is there a solution for stopping **any** kind of function after specified time ?

Comment: The function snowflakes is only being called one, so you don't need to remove it. What you need to do is remove the effects of the snowflakes funcion. What is it doing inside? Paste it and we can figure out how to remove it's effects.

Comment: Ok i edited my question (up) and added full code for snowflakes class.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). That helped me very much. Btw this should be easier to use. 1st timer argument in this case 3000 ms (var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(**3000**, 1) should mean how long something would last. This would be much easier to setup (just like in jQuery). Anyway thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This question already had an answer accepted before I could post my answer but I'll answer anyway.

You could add an internal Timer object to your SnowFlake object that upon completion removes the SnowFlake from parent display object container. Here is an example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.TriangleCulling;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _spawnTime:int = 5;
        private var _spawnTimeCounter:int;

        private var _triangles:Vector.<Triangle>;
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            _triangles = new Vector.<Triangle>();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        }
        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            if (_spawnTimeCounter > _spawnTime)
            {
                var triangle:Triangle = new Triangle(random(1, 5), 3000)
                triangle.x = random(0, stage.stageWidth);
                addChild(triangle);
                triangle.drop();

                _spawnTimeCounter = 0;
            }

            _spawnTimeCounter++;
        }

        private function random(min:Number, max:Number):Number
        {
            return Math.floor((Math.random() * ((1 + max) - min)) + min);

        }
    }

}

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

internal class Triangle extends Sprite
{
    public var speed:Number;

    private var _delay:Number;
    private var _timer:Timer;

    public function Triangle(speed:Number = 1, delay:Number = 0) 
    { 
        this.speed = speed;
        _delay = delay;

        init(); 

    }// end function

    public function init():void
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
        graphics.drawTriangles(Vector.<Number>([0, 20, 15, 0, 30, 20]));
        graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

    public function drop():void
    {
        if (parent && !hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME))
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

            if (_delay > 0)
            {
                _timer = new Timer(_delay, 1);
                _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
                _timer.start();

            }// end if

        }// end if

    }// end function

    public function remove():void
    {
        if (parent) parent.removeChild(this);

    }// end function

    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        y += speed;

    }// end function

    private function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        remove();

    }// end function

}// end class
```

If run the code, you can see continuously falling snow flakes (triangles) falling at varying speeds but each snow flake disappears after 3 seconds.

[image]